# Blogger: template error

Tags: blogger

When I try uploading my template I get following error message:

We were unable to save your template.

Your template could not be parsed as it is not well-formed. Please make sure all XML elements are closed properly. XML error message:
Invalid variable declaration in page skin: This attribute is not recognized as part of the variable definition. Input: min

I downloaded it yesterday as I wanted to make some changes to it. however the changes did not work, so I want to upload the old one. But I get this error.

Can someone help me? Thx

Answer (score 0):

More information about the code would be helpful, from error it is clear that some of *XML elements are not closed properly* or *there are some Invalid variable declarations.* 
please share a link to the template if it freely available or screenshot of code where blogger is showing error.